# near Cheonan, in what became South Korea when the peninsula was divided in 1945, after World War II.

Tags: syntactic-analysis

I don't understand " in what became South Korea" means. 
In other word, I'd like to know the structure and meaning : in what became South Korea

Yu was born on Dec. 16, 1902, the second daughter of five children to Christian parents near Cheonan, in what became South Korea when the peninsula was divided in 1945, after World War II.

Comment: Cheonan is in South Korea.  But it did not become South Korea until 1945--it was just Korea.

Answer (score 1):

*What* refers to Cheonan, the area in question.

We can paraphrase the sentence like this:

*Yu was born on Dec. 16, 1902, the second daughter of five children to Christian parents near Cheonan, **in the land which started to belong to** South Korea when the peninsula was divided in 1945, after World War II.*

Comment: Thank you Enguroo. It seems very clear to me. I thought in the area instead of in the land.

Comment: Right, that very place became South Korea later. Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: I disagree that _what_ refers only to Cheonan. I would say it refers to all the territory which became South Korea, that is Cheonan and all the other areas which now make up South Korea. Another example is that of [Pocahontas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocahontas) who was born in the Tsenacommacah in _what became_ the state of Virginia. Virginia covers more than the Tsenacommacah but did not exist as a state until nearly 200 years later than the birth of Pocahontas.

Comment: Dear BoldBen. I think your opinion is the same as Enguroo's analysis: "what" refers to all the territory or land which bccame South Korea in 1945 when it was emancipated from Japan.